# Python list inside a dictionary with the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

I am running a python program using Visual Studio Code, and the data for it looks like this:

```py
data = {
    [0, 0, 0] : 0,
    [0, 0, 1] : 0,
    [0, 1, 0] : 0,
    [0, 1, 1] : 0,
    [1, 0, 0] : 1,
    [1, 0, 1] : 1,
    [1, 1, 0] : 1,
    [1, 1, 1] : 1
}
```

But when I run this it gives me the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How can I store lists in a dictionary? I have the feeling that a list cannot be a key, but I want something like this, not a variable for each of the lists.

Comment: You cannot have `list` as key in dict. Instead you can use a `tuple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least tuples instead of list, so:

```
data = {
    (0, 0, 0) : 0,
...
}
```

Note parenthesis, instead of square brackets. Tuples are like lists, except are immutable and can be used as keys in dictionary without a hassle.

Answer (score 4):

Keys in a dictionary have to be immutable. Lists are mutable, so they can't be keys.
You can change them into tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use `tuples`

```
data = {
    (0, 0, 0) : 0,
    (0, 0, 1) : 0,
    (0, 1, 0) : 0,
    (0, 1, 1) : 0,
    (1, 0, 0) : 1,
    (1, 0, 1) : 1,
    (1, 1, 0) : 1,
    (1, 1, 1) : 1
}
```

Comment: Those are tuples. Sets would be `{0, 0, 0}`. Also you can't use sets as keys either, you need `frozenset` for this.

Comment: You are correct @Radoslaw. My bad. Have rectified it